# Java do while look proper coding return value?

Tags: java

My question is about the increment I am asking how do you return data from the do while loop that is suppose to be set in each value.

the totalSales inside of my do while loop should have data set when it comes out of the loop it does not save the data into the totalSales or totalItems values.

```
// The system print out values are empty.
      System.out.printf(salesID + " you entered a total of: " + totalItems + "With a total sales of $%15.2f" + totalSales);
```

I am trying to return data from a freaky do while or the if statement loop and it will not return the items I set why?

```
// yesno to n for first loop through.

do {
      System.out.println("Welcome Sales ID: " + salesID + " please enter the samsung TV sold: \n");
      samsungProduct = scanValue.next();
      System.out.println("Please enter your total TV sales amounts individually for today \n");
      singleSale = scanValue.nextDouble();
      totalSales = totalSales + singleSale;
      totalItems = totalItems++;
      System.out.println("Do you want to enter another sales total(Y/N): \n ");
      yesNo = scanValue.next();

}        while (!yesNo.equalsIgnoreCase("N"));

// get the items set inside of the do while loop.

// The system print out values are empty.
      System.out.printf(salesID + " you entered a total of: " + totalItems + "With a total sales         of  $%15.2f" + totalSales);
```

Comment: *"freaky do while or the if statement loop"*? Please explain what you **expect**, what **actually happens**, and how those are different.

Comment: @Wendell - `totalItems = totalItems++;` is totally redundant. Just `++totalItems;` suffice.

Comment: @Mehesh - It's not redundant, its just not going to do what the writer means it too, likely. It's going to set totalItems to it's original value.

Comment: totalItems++; is equivalant to totalItems=totalItems+1;. So totalItems = totalItems++; is unnecessary. totalItems++; is enough.

Comment: My question is about the increment I am asking how do you return data from the do while loop that is suppose to be set in each value.

the totalSales inside of my do while loop should have data set when it comes out of the loop it does not save the data into the totalSales or totalItems values.

// The system print out values are empty.
System.out.printf(salesID + " you entered a total of: " + totalItems + "With a total sales of $%15.2f" + totalSales);

Comment: what is the precise error/exception?

Comment: Continually amazed how many people write `x = x++;`

Answer (score 6):

This is wrong:

```
totalItems = totalItems++;
```

You should do

```
totalItems++;
```

What you did is equal to:

```
int temp = totalItems;
totalItems = totalItems + 1;// (totalItems++)
totalItems = temp;
```

Comment: @RMT - Thanks, but it's actually Josh Bloch's example, I just couldn't find the reference...

Answer (score 4):

This is your problem: `totalItems = totalItems++;`

After this line of code the value of the totalItems is not changed.

Use `totalItems++;` instead

The problem is that i++ increment i, but returns the old value. So when you do `i = i++` you assign the old value to i - so i is unchanged.

Comment: Actually that isnt the problem the problem is  singleSale = scanValue.nextDouble(); I simply want the values like this one to stay set when coming out of the loop. When It gets to the System.out.println outside of the do while loop I lose all set values inside of the loop. So, everything is set to zero which is driving me batty poops :)

Answer (score 2):

`totalItems = totalItems++;` is a do nothing operation.

**See here**: [Post Increment Operator And Assignment](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/PostIncrementOperatorAndAssignment)

---

```
System.out.printf(salesID + " you entered a total of: " + totalItems 
    + "With a total sales of $%15.2f" + totalSales);
```

should be

```
System.out.printf(salesID + " you entered a total of: " + totalItems 
       + "With a total sales of $%15.2f", totalSales);
                                       ^^^^
```

Comment: scanValue.nextDouble(); I simply want the values like this one to stay set when coming out of the loop. When It gets to the System.out.println outside of the do while loop I lose all set values inside of the loop. So, everything is set to zero which is driving me batty poops :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your loop, but running it (having created the appropriate variables) results in this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '15.2f'
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2432)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:920)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:821)
    at ScratchMain.main(ScratchMain.java:26)
```

This tells me that you're not using `printf` correctly. If you use `$f` (or the more complex `$%15.2f`), then the value you want to put there needs to be passed to `printf` as *an argument* and not just concatenated to the `String`:

```
System.out.printf(salesID + " you entered a total of: " + totalItems + "With a total sales         of  $%15.2f", totalSales);
```

Also, you have the code `totalItems = totalItems++;` in there, which is effectively a no-op (i.e. it does nothing). Replace it with *either* `totalItems++;` or `totalItems = totalItems + 1;` (if you want to make it explicit).